# Cannot push GitHub changes form Atom editor

Tags: github, request, pull

I've been giving GitHub's Atom editor a try but am struggling to get the GitHub integration to work. I cloned a repository from my account and cannot push the changes back to GitHub.

I just added a test file called "otherfile.html", committed those changes, and tried pushing it. It comes up with a login for GitHub twice were I enter my username ans a Personal Access Token (I have two-factor authentication setup). Then it gives me this error message:

```
The tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Try pulling before pushing again. Or, to force push, hold cmd or ctrl while clicking.
```

Not sure if it is related, but the GitHub tab says this:

```
No Pull request could be found fo the branch master on the repository gabrielewig/gabrielewig.github.io

You can manually pin a GitHub pull request to the current branch by entering its URL:
```

Any help would be appreciated! The exact repo can be found here: https://github.com/gabrielewig/gabrielewig.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, switch to command line to see what `git status` give you.
And do a `git pull` if it still mention your master branch is behind its remote counterpart.

Second, check your `git config credential.helper` value.
On Windows for instance, the [GCM helper](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/wiki/How-the-Git-Credential-Managers-works#github-2-factor-authentication) would need your username/password (not PTA) in order to create a PTA.

---

Finally, do check "[Improved pull request experience in GitHub for Atom](https://blog.github.com/2018-09-04-github-for-atom/)" (Sept. 2018)

> we’ve added a pull request list view. Now you can see the most recent pull requests in the GitHub tab Ctrl+8 with information such as:
>
> - Author’s avatar
> - Title of the pull request
> - Pull request number
> - CI status
> - “Last Updated” information
>
> In addition to seeing more information about your existing pull requests, you can also open a new pull request directly from Atom.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1314285/44668326-ee88c580-a9d1-11e8-8a8c-0d8b68d1bd76.png]